# Retry a specific piece of code in a TestNG code if the test fails, not the whole test

Tags: java, testng

I want to retry some method specific code if the TestNG test fails, and not retry the whole test.

I have looked into custom test Listeners and Retry analyzers from here https://github.com/haojiwu/testng-retry-example. This will rerun the whole test if it fails I want to some method specific code.

```java
@Test()
public void testStuff() {
    String var1;
    String var2;

    /* Code specific to this test and should only be ran once. */
    doSomething(param1)

    /* Contains code looking for files that may or not be ready by the time the code is ran. */
    /* I want to try this code then wait and retry up to a max of 3 retries. */
    assertStuff(var1, var2);
}
```

I want to do the code in doSomething(param1), the try the stuff in assertStuff(var1, var2) if the asserts in that fail I want to wait like 5 seconds and then retry the assertStuff(var1, var2) code if the asserts pass then the test pass, else retry up to 2 more times.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please add the code that you tried and clarify where you got stuck. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use [TestNG retryAnalyzer](https://www.swtestacademy.com/retry-failed-tests-testng-iretryanalyzer/) feature, but only for the `assertStuff(var1, var2)` part.

Therefore you should move the `doSomething(param1)` into a separate method, annotated with `@BeforeClass` (or `@BeforeMethod`):

```
...
@BeforeClass
public void initSomething() {
    doSomething(param1);
}

@Test(retryAnalyzer = ThreeRetries.class)
public void testStuff() {
    String var1;
    String var2;

    assertStuff(var1, var2);
}
```

Alternatively you can use `@Test` annotation for mandatory part and declare dependency between tests, e.g.:

```
...
@Test
public void initSomething() {
    doSomething(param1);
}

@Test(retryAnalyzer = ThreeRetries.class, dependsOnMethods = "initSomething")
public void testStuff() {
    String var1;
    String var2;

    assertStuff(var1, var2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way of getting this done without having to depend on RetryAnalyzer (one issue with RetryAnalyzer if you are not using the latest beta version viz., `7.0.0-beta5` or higher is that you would need to take responsibility of pruning the duplicate test results that result from the retrial).

You could instead build a simple polling mechanism around your `assertStuff()` method and have it return `true` or `false` which you can assert.

Here's an example. For the sake of ease, I have leveraged using `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait` since its APIs are pretty concise

```java
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestClass {
  private static final int max = 5;

  @Test
  public void testStuff() {
    doSomething();
    boolean wasAsserted = assertStuff(2);
    Assert.assertTrue(wasAsserted);
  }

  @Test
  public void testStuffThatFails() {
    doSomething();
    boolean wasAsserted = assertStuff(10);
    Assert.assertTrue(wasAsserted);
  }

  private boolean assertStuff(int retries) {
    final AtomicInteger integer = new AtomicInteger(0);
    Supplier<Integer> input = integer::getAndIncrement;
    FluentWait<Supplier<Integer>> checker =
        new FluentWait<>(input)
            .pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
            .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    try {
      return checker.until(getCondition(retries));
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private Function<Supplier<Integer>, Boolean> getCondition(int retries) {
    return integerSupplier -> {
      int current = integerSupplier.get();
      return current == retries || current > max;
    };
  }

  private void doSomething() {
    System.err.println("I did something");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple, we try like this also

```
    int iterate=5;
    boolean status=false;

    while(iterate >=1 && status ==false) {

        try {
            assertEquals("false", "true");
            status=true;
        }catch (AssertionError e) {
            iterate--;
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
    }
```